# Multi-tenancy: How do I delete a tenant?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, multi-tenant

I have a system with shared multitenancy, which means each table contains data for all tenants with a TenantId column to distinguish between them.

Provisioning a new tenant is quick and easy, however now I'm facing a challenge with deleting a single tenant.

Given that entities depend on each other for consistency, how do I delete a tenant easily from my database, while the system is in use by other tenants?

The system uses SQL Server 2008 R2, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right - this is the classical case for use of `FOREIGN KEYS` with `ON CASCADE` option. You only delete one record from master tenants table and due to proper chain of FKeys the system deletes related records or updates the reference columns with `NULL` or `DEFAULT` value

Sometimes will not work in cases where table references itself with DELETE ON CASCADE

Answer (score 1):

As Oleg has pointed out FK with ON CASCADE option should help. But since you haven't shown us the schema, I am not very sure whether there is a possibility of system throwing an error saying "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint causes cycles or Multiple cascade paths". If you see this error then may be instead of CASCADE DELETE add a INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger to do the job.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Tenants_Delete 
ON dbo.Tenants
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN;
    --Delete from the Child and Master table as per your need here.
    --Make use of the magic table DELETED
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach: If deleting the tenant causes too much headache, you may be able to use a workaround.

Simply add a boolean column `active` to your tenant table. Then introduce a view that selects only the active tenants. Adjust your stored procedures to look up the data in this view rather than in the original tenant table.