# How to use CASCADE DELETE for removing all tenant data

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, cascade

I want to remove all the entities related to a tenant from the a multi-tenant database when one tenant is removed. I'm working with EF Core and Microsoft SQL Server, although I guess this topic is not limited to those technologies.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779386/2651069), it is said that:

> this is the classical case for use of FOREIGN KEYS with ON CASCADE option

However, I've not managed to make it work. It seems that since the *tenantized* entities are also linked between them, cycles would be created. I’ve created a simple app to test this in isolation, you can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/tgomezgil/cascadedeletetenant/src/master/). When trying to update the database according to the migration, I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Posts_Tenants_TenantId' on table 'Posts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

My DbContext and entities:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=TestCascadeDelete;Trusted_Connection=True");
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>(b => b.HasOne<Tenant>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.TenantId));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(b => b.HasOne<Tenant>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.TenantId));
    }
}
public class Tenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
public class Blog
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}
public class Post
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is: **is this possible? and if it is, what should I change in my configuration?** I’ve [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127512/2651069) that making the FK’s between entities nullable could solve the problem, but I don’t want to make that change just to make this work. I've also seen [this answer](http://this%20is%20the%20classical%20case%20for%20use%20of%20FOREIGN%20KEYS%20with%20ON%20CASCADE%20option) for replacing the CASCADE DELETE with a trigger, but I don't like this option.

Comment: Do all tables have the column `TenantId` ?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts, yes.

Comment: You could try [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4059/script-to-delete-data-from-sql-server-tables-with-foreign-key-constraints/) approach. Summary, it generates a delete script based on the foreign keys. Then you could add `WHERE TenantId = X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "multiple cascade paths" for `Post`:

```
Tenant => Blog => Post
Tenant => Post
```

`Post.TenantId` is redundant as a Post is contained in a tenant-specific `Blog`.

There are various possibilities:

- remove Post.TenantId
- remove the reference between Tenant and Post (replace by Blog and Post)
- add correct `OnDelete()` behavior ([MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencereferencebuilder.ondelete))